# std:mutex'es as members of objects that will go into containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, smart-pointers

I'm kind of aware that this is less of a question and more of a discussion, but I believe one or more answers can be provided, so here you go.

I have a class like so

```
class MyAwesomeObject {
public:
    std::mutex theListMutex;
    std::list<int> theList;
};
```

Now, I believe the intention is quite obvious, and the example is purposely academic -- although not that far from my reality -- so let's just go ahead. Then my application handles tons of such objects, all of which are stored in a vector somewhere else, and everything is sort of fine. The troubles start when I compile. I'm using VS2012 but I believe other compilers might emit similar errors:

```
error C2248: 'std::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::mutex'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(116) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\mutex(107) : see declaration of 'std::mutex'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'MyApp::MyAwesomeObject ::MyAwesomeObject (const MyApp::MyAwesomeObject &)'
```

which meaning is quite clear to me, having gone through lots of other questions here in SO, all of which said basically that "mutexes can't be copied" and I'm fine with it. So my strategy so far has been to make the mutex a `shared_ptr<mutex>` and be done with it. The only "drawback" is that now I have to use the silly dereferencing syntax when I access the mutex, which of course is not silly at all, just a bit awkward and out-standing in between all the other dot notations I use all over the place.

Now, on to my question: is using a shared pointer the right way of solving the problem? Might have I used a unique pointer instead, since as far as I'm aware I'm not transferring ownership to anyone else (unless calling methods on a pointer that is member of an object is actually a form of ownership transfer)? Are there other ways to go around the fact that mutexes can't be copied?

Comment: What are you trying to do that creates this error? A mutex shouldn't ever need to be copied.  If you are in that situation, your design needs reviewing.

Comment: I have a vector of such objects, and this vector is protected with a mutex of its own. Every object of class MyAwesomeObject, as you can see, contains a list which needs to be protected with a mutex. Now, my application needs to randomly access said vector, pick up one of those objects, access its list, do some stuff on it, and the object as well, and store the object back in the vector it comes from. Besides, I'm also accessing the vector with a range-based loop which I thought used references which should create no need for copies, but I've done some testing and some copying seems to happen.

Comment: Make it a vector of `shared_ptr<MyAwesomeObject>` which allows you to have the non-copyable mutex inside your objects. Don't go sharing mutexes, that is BAD.

Comment: What's with [the troll edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17487192/revisions)? :) I like my words to convey meaning, not just look like faux latin. _[Hint for the uninitiated: Mut(ual)Ex(clusion)]_

Comment: I really can't see the point of latinising technical terms just because. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37455/mutexes-or-mutices besides in this case I was using the word `mutex` referring to `std::mutex` which leaves no doubt as to whether it's appropriate to pluralise it or not. Would you refer to a vector containing object of class Animal as a vector of Animals, by any chance?

Comment: There is no unnecessary copying in a range-based `for`, maybe you're doing `for (auto x : v)` when you should be doing `for (auto& x : v)`

Answer (score 2):

> So my strategy so far has been to make the mutex a `shared_ptr<mutex>`

Wait. Why would the mutex be shared across various instances? Do you realise this ends up protecting more than one `theList` with the same mutex?

You can't just drop `shared_ptr`s on things and pretend it solves things. In this case, it changes semantics. I would expect the right semantics here to be: each new `MyAwesomeObject` object will have its own mutex to protect its own `theList`.

Comment: I agree with your first two paragraphs, but the 3rd has an issue.  This use of 'distinct_lock' does not cause the mutex to be acquired during the copy of the other data members.  Most situations where you want to be able to copy mutex safe objects (which is reasonably rare), you also want to lock the data while you're performing the copy.

Comment: @DaveS hmm, very good point. I will just go along and suggest `unique_lock` then. Ugh, no, that's still not good. Woah, what a mess.

Comment: Uhm. You answer clarifies a number of things to me, thanks. However I can't see how making the `distinct_lock` struct would help me. No, wait, I clearly see it, I'm just baffled by the fact that it's not in the standard library. I'm sure there must be a way of doing the same with standard features, although I can't see one. As for the private/public thing: yes, I know. If I was writing code that other might see/use in the future, I'd most likely go for the private/getter approach.

Comment: My usual solution is to write our own copy/move constructors/assignment operators, which don't copy/move the mutex, but instead acquires the mutex, and copies the other data.  Making that generic so you don't have manually write all of the operators would be nice, but it's tricky

Comment: unique_lock is movable, not copyable, as much as a shared_lock for what it's worth. I understand the problem and how you are trying to solve it here, and it's quite a bit of a mess. I might be better off following Tony's suggestion of going for a vector of shared pointers, this time.

Comment: @DaveS I don't think it can be made generic without requiring some hoop jumping from the end user :/

Answer (score 2):

No, using a `std::shared_ptr` is **not** the right way to deal with this problem.

If you want your object to be copyable, then define a copy constructor that locks the mutex in the source, and then copies the contents. Mike Spertus wrote a guest post for my blog about this: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-safe-copy-constructors.html

If you only want your object to be movable (which, as Jonathan pointed out, is all that is required to store it in a vector), then you can either define a move constructor, as above, or follow Jonathan's suggestion of using a `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a `shared_ptr` as there will never be more than one owner of the mutex.

I would use `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>`, which makes you object move-only, not copyable, but that's OK for storing them in a `vector`.  That way you can transfer ownership of the list and the associated mutex from one object to another, but cannot copy them.

That means your `MyAwesomeObject` will have an empty "moved-from" state, where it has no mutex and so its list shouldn't be used.  You should add a member to query whether it's in that state or not, so users can tell if they've been given an empty object without a mutex:

```
class MyAwesomeObject {
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> theListMutex;
    std::list<int> theList;

public:
    bool valid() const { return (bool)theListMutex; }
};
```

Comment: That defeats the whole purpose of not having a vector of pointers in the first place.

Comment: Why? What is "the whole purpose of not having a vector of pointers"?

Answer (score 0):

Mutex strategy should be based on the "scope of transaction" concept and not per objet / or per this . per that.

Now a Scope of Transaction could be

- A: Manipulating single shared data structure say a list etc
- B: Manipulating Multiple shared data structure say multiple list,counters  & etc
- C: Manipulating Multiple shared data structure & shared extrenal [could be file descriptor , or db connection etc ]
  resource

Comment: How's this helping? I am in case B and I don't see having the mutex inside the object as a violation of the scope of transaction principle.

Comment: @Morpheu5 well I am stating a general guiding hint.If you read the original question User is discussing of creating mutex per object.

Now i am trying to say is its not about object , but a 'transaction' which could be just a small code which is manipulating a shared property within the object or a larger data structure.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if *you* read the original question, you'd have figured out that I am the OP, and I am saying that your answer doesn't bring me one bit closer to solving my problem.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Well I am sorry if my answer is not helping you , may be once you have more experience in synhronizing stuff & efficiency & deadlocks issue you will that day on wards understand what I am trying to say. Do think about a situation when you using lock per object approach and end up having them recursively .

Comment: I figure that that day will come way before the day you'll learn not to assume things about people. I do have enough experience with "synchronization stuff & efficiency & deadlocks" (can't figure what's efficiency doing in the mix, though) and I know that my code, which I designed, will not be able to request locks recursively. If that was the case, I'd be having way worse problems than a bit of confusion about smart pointers in C++. Bottom line: generic barely-on-topic answers to precise questions tend not to help and are generally uncalled for.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a `deque` or `list`instead of a `vector`, as it does not impose the moveable / copyable requirement on the type it stores (assuming you use `emplace_*` methods construction to store the elements in the container, and you aren't copying the container, of course).